# Apache 2.2 module

Tags: delphi, apache, apache2, delphi-2010

I want to create an apache 2(2.2.21 to be more specific) module in Delphi 2010, however I find it extremely difficult due to the fact that delphi no longer supports creating a web server application as an apache 2.X module.

I've searched for hours but no luck, changed a few constants like:

```
MODULE_MAGIC_COOKIE = $041503232;
MODULE_MAGIC_NUMBER_MAJOR = 20051115;
MODULE_MAGIC_NUMBER_MINOR = 0;
```

based on what I've found in my searches.

in my httpd.conf file I've added:

```
LoadModule mymodule_module modules/mod_mymodule.so
```

however, apache fails to load it, it says that it cannot find the module, but I've copied it to apache's module folder, I'm certain that it's there, I believe something fails in the initiation of the module, I do not know what tho.

I'm using:

- Delphi 2010
- Apache 2.2.21

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to stick to Delphi 2010 if you can achieve it with prior Delphi version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made an Apache 2.2 module under the [xxm](http://xxm.sourceforge.net/) project, and indeed had to do a lot of work to get the library registration in order. The project is primarily made in Delphi 7, but I've taken care to use AnsiString/WideString specifically wherever possible, so it should compile and work under newer Delphi versions. You can view the source here:

http://xxm.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/xxm/trunk/Delphi/apache/

Comment: +1 thank you Stijn, the reason for using Delphi is because I want to use a few libs that are supported only on Delphi, modifying them in order to move to FreePascal will probably give a lot of headaches in the future, but at the moment, I've managed to write a simple module using FreePascal + Lazarus(damn it's fast!), however it only exposes Apache's API rather than having stuff exposed in classes... I'll have to look at XXM

Comment: Please do, let me know if you could use help. The project is in desperate need of supporters/enthusiasts/community.

Comment: Accepted your answer, it seems that you've done a very good job with the apache module, congratulations!